# buttons property in worksheet class error on drop down cell with userform pop up excel

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, userform, vba

I'm trying to have a userform pop-up when I select a specific value from a drop-down menu.  It's giving me a "Unable to get the Buttons property of the Worksheet Class" error.  I can pull up the userform using a button.  When I use the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G9")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("G9")
        Case "Sporadic (<5)"
            spor_pay.Show
            'Cells(2, 2) = "what's wrong"
    End Select
End If
End Sub`
```

I get the error above.  However, if I delete the userform (spor_pay is the userform), and try to just enter a value in another cell, the error doesn't pop up.  What am I doing wrong with this?  Again, if I create a macro from a button, and have the form pop up, there isn't a problem at all.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's the line in the form which causes the problem?

Comment: The line `End Sub'` should just be `End Sub` but I guess is a typing error. Anycase, your code works for me, it shows the userform, so what is your problem?